# How can I change the number of int value to another number in a column?

Tags: python

The dataframe dataset has two columns 'Review' and 'Label' and dtypes of 'Label' is int.
[image]

I would like to change the number in the 'Label' column. So I tried to use replace() but it doesn't change well as you can see in the below picture.

[image]

Comment: Please properly format your code and desired output as text in the post rather than posting images. See here for more tips on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and quick solution(besides `replace`) would be to use a `Series.map()` [method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html). You could define a dictionary with keys corresponding to the values you want to replace and values set to the new values you wish to have. Then, use an anonymous function(or normal one) to replace your values

```
d={1:0,2:0,4:1,5:1}
dataset['label']=dataset['label'].map(lambda x: d[x])
```

This will replace 1 and 2 with 0, and 4 and 5 with 1.

I am not sure what your criteria for "well" is, as the `replace` method will work for you and essentially achieve the same result(and is more optimized than `map` for replacement purposes).

What might be causing the issues is that `replace`  has a default arg `inplace=False`. Thus, your results will not affect each other and you will have to combine them into `dataset['label']=dataset['label'].replace([1,2,4,5],[0,0,1,1])` or `dataset['label'].replace([1,2,4,5],[0,0,1,1],inplace=True)`

Comment: Thank you @Alex.Kh
I followed your comment and the result came like this.
0       {1: 0, 2: 0, 4: 1, 5: 1}
1       {1: 0, 2: 0, 4: 1, 5: 1}  
2       {1: 0, 2: 0, 4: 1, 5: 1}
3       {1: 0, 2: 0, 4: 1, 5: 1}

Comment: @Genie my mistake, forgot to use the `x` value as a key. Take a look now and consider trying `replace` as I told you as well. It should be faster than `map`

Comment: These codes solved  the problem :) Thank you so much !!
I am so happy :)
dataset['label']=dataset['label'].replace([1,2,4,5],[0,0,1,1]) or dataset['label'].replace([1,2,4,5],[0,0,1,1],inplace=True)

Comment: @Genie glad it helped!